# How do I format a number with commas?

Tags: c#, numbers, tostring

```
int a = 10000000;
a.ToString();
```

How do I make the output?

> 10,000,000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try `N0` for no decimal part:

```
string formatted = a.ToString("N0"); // 10,000,000
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a.ToString("#");? In my case I need the value to be blank on zero, but I need commas too - or should I just do it like a.ToString("#,###,###,###,###,###,###")?

Comment: You probably need to do do an if{}else{} block to deal with the zero.

Comment: @cms how to achive this **`10,24,78,000`**

Answer (score 12):

You can also do String.Format:

```
int x = 100000;
string y = string.Empty;
y = string.Format("{0:#,##0.##}", x); 
//Will output: 100,000
```

If you have decimal, the same code will output 2 decimal places:

```
double x = 100000.2333;
string y = string.Empty;
y = string.Format("{0:#,##0.##}", x); 
//Will output: 100,000.23
```

To make comma instead of decimal use this:

```
double x = 100000.2333;
string y = string.Empty;
y = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:#,##0.##}", x);
```

Comment: how about if decimal separator is commas?

Answer (score 10):

`a.ToString("N0")`

See also: [Standard Numeric Formatting Strings from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler String.Format option:

```
int a = 10000000;
String.Format("{0:n0}", a); //10,000,000
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler for c#6 or higher:

```
string formatted = $"{a:N0}";
```

Comment: Saving the people a search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score -3):

a.tostring("00,000,000")

Comment: I think you took the // literally I think the OP was meaning to write it as commented code.

Comment: you could try a = "10,000,000" ;)