# Adding comma between longer numbers

Tags: c#

I'm trying to put comma's between long numbers automatically, but so far without success. I'm probably making a very simple mistake, but so far I can't figure it out. This is the code I currently have, but for some reason I'm getting 123456789 as the output.

```
    string s = "123456789";
    string.Format("{0:#,###0}", s);
    MessageBox.Show(s); // Needs to output 123,456,789
```

Comment: You're missing the `{`, but also could just use `N` for general number format. Also, your input is a string, not a number.

Comment: If you look at each character in the format string, can you tell me what each does?

Comment: I think you need to add a curly bracket first of all.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, but removing the brackets is not the solution.

Comment: its already posted, here is few [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545633/add-commas-using-string-format-for-number-and) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699921/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas) I am sure it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = 123456789;

// these two lines amount to the same thing
Console.WriteLine(input.ToString("N0"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N0}", input));
```

If, as per your question, you need to start with a `string`:

```
var stringInput = "123456789";
var input = int.Parse(stringInput);

// these two lines amount to the same thing
Console.WriteLine(input.ToString("N0"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N0}", input));
```

You'll possibly also need to take culture into account when parsing/formatting. See the overloads that take an `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string value = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", 123456789);
```

In your code you are missing the initial `{` in the format string, and then number formatting options apply to numbers, while your `s` is a string.
You could convert the string to a number with `int.Parse`:

```
int s = int.Parse("123456789");
string value = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", 123456789);
MessageBox.Show(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (you need to pass `String.Format()` a number, not another `String`):

```
Int32 i = 123456789;
String s = String.Format("{0:#,###0}", i);
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

But consider the format string you're using...there are cleaner options available, as others are suggesting.

Comment: This worked. The input is always a string though, because it's needs to be loaded from an external source. I converted it to Int32, used your code, and then converted it back to a string. This worked. I will try to make it cleaner, but still your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the number formatting information on MSDN: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), or optionally at the custom format strings: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

For custom number formats:

> The "," character serves as both a group separator and a number scaling specifier.

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1,234,567,890      
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,,", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1,235
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with your code, that's it's hard to describe every detail.

Look at this example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  using System;

  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      const int Number = 123456789;
      var formatted = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", Number);

      Console.WriteLine(formatted);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```