# How can show comma in decimal number in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to show number with comma. I am getting like 20.85 But i need like 20,85. Note: (i dont have web.config in my project) can we create another class and define cost culture(localization) please suggest me code for this .i am new to c# and i am fresher . please help me.

```
[DisplayName("Cost")]

public decimal Value { get; set; }
```

I getting this:

```
20.85
```

But I want this instead:

```
20,85
```

Comment: did you use this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/699929/10193401

Comment: Try Value.ToString("#,##");

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement that.

By changing culture info at runtime:

```cs
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
```

Or you can change value format:

```
 decimal value = 20.85M;
 NumberFormatInfo formatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
 formatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
 string y = string.Format(formatInfo,"{0:###0.##}", value);
 Console.WriteLine("value: " + y); // value: 20,85
 Console.ReadKey();
```