# How to display numeric in 3 digit grouping

Tags: c#

How to display a numeric numbers in 3 digit groupings.

For Ex: `1234` to be `1,234` or `1 234`

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Answer (score 23):

From the **The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier** section in [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
double dblValue = -12445.6789;
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays -12,445.68

Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N1", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE")));
// Displays -12 445,7

int intValue = 123456789;
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 123,456,789.0
```

Comment: "N1" will add decimal places, "n0" will chop them off which seems to be what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
String.Format("{0:n0}", yourNumber);
```

If you want spaces instead of commas try this:

```
String.Format("{0:n0}", yourNumber).Replace(",", " ");
```

**Edit:** Marc makes a good point about being cuturally aware so this would be a better way to replace the group separators:

```
String.Format("{0:n0}", yourNumber)
    .Replace(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberGroupSeparator, " ");
```

Answer (score 6):

The comma case is easy enough - `.ToString("###,###,###")`; for the space? perhaps cheat and replace the commas? Or write a custom culture with space as the group separator?

Note also that this is culture-dependent. The comma above doesn't mean "comma", it means the culture's group separator. You might want to specify a fixed culture if this matters (perhaps the invariant culture).

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
yourDecimal.ToString("#,##0");
```

or

```
yourDecimal.ToString("#,##0.00");
```

for decimal places.

Comment: Most simple and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2):

Compare those:

```
 .ToString("#,##0", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))

 .ToString("#,##0", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"))

 .ToString("#,##0", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"))

 .ToString("#,##0")
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

use this sample code:

```
int test1 = 123456;
string test2 = test1.ToString("N0");
```

**output= 123,456**

Answer (score 1):

You Can simply Use Visual Basic TriState for it
For Example:

```
textBox1.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber(textBox1.Text, 0, TriState.True);
```

String formatting was not what i needed! but this one done what i wanted!
hope it solves your problem too :)

Answer (score 0):

Also this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#,###0}", 1234567));
```

Would result: `1,234,567`