# Digit grouping in C's printf

Tags: c, printf, grouping, digit

I wish to output large numbers with thousand-separators (commas or spaces) — basically the same as in [How to display numeric in 3 digit grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872094/how-to-display-numeric-in-3-digit-grouping) but using `printf` in C (GNU, 99).

If printf does not support digit grouping natively, how can I achieve this with something like `printf("%s", group_digits(number))`?

It must support negative integers and preferably floats, too.

Comment: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.sys.hp.mpe/2006-02/msg00074.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a number from 1123456789 to 1,123,456,789 in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c)

Comment: Beware "strange" grouping methods, there may be more than [indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).

Comment: @pmg it reminds me of the US date format...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can use [POSIX printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), try

```
#include <locale.h>
setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); /* use user selected locale */
printf("%'d", 1000000);
```

Comment: Not even something like "de_DE". Basically if you want the program to run anywhere, it has to be "", meaning whatever the user has selected. You can also limit yourself to LC_NUMERIC locale category.

Comment: I don't really like this method because it doesn't seem to port to other languages. Take Python, for example, I tried `print "%'d" % 1000` and it immediately threw an error. `'` seems to be a non-standard format specifier. For that reason, this answer should be taken with a grain of salt if one programs in more languages than just C, and more environments than just the POSIX-compliant ones. Considering the narrow scope of the question, though, I'll give an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a compact way of doing it:

```
// format 1234567.89 -> 1 234 567.89
extern char *strmoney(double value){
    static char result[64];
    char *result_p = result;
    char separator = ' ';
    size_t tail;

    snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%.2f", value);

    while(*result_p != 0 && *result_p != '.')
        result_p++;

    tail = result + sizeof(result) - result_p;

    while(result_p - result > 3){
        result_p -= 3;
        memmove(result_p + 1, result_p, tail);
        *result_p = separator;
        tail += 4;
    }

    return result;
}
```

For example, a call to `strmoney(1234567891.4568)` returns the string `"1 234 567 891.46"`. You can easily replace the space with another separator (such as a comma) by changing the `separator` variable at the top of the function.

Comment: Thanks, Erick; that's brilliant use of a static to avoid having to declare a separate buffer, though one must be careful to avoid constructs like printf("%s|%s\n", strmoney(1234567890.1234567890), strmoney(-9876543210.9876543210)) which print the same value twice. +1 for using memmove too. Hope you don't mind my beautifying and annotating your code!

Comment: @Gnubie I don't wanna be *that guy*, but comments are bad. They represent a failure to clearly write code. If you have to explain how something works, then it needs to be **re-written**, not explained. Clever code is error-prone, and comments used to describe said clever code both create more work for a maintainer, and represent a lie waiting to happen.

Comment: I took the liberty of refactoring the function and tidying up the language. Honestly, though, this function needs more than just a refactor. For example, returning a static char array is problematic because any pointer you have to the returned value will change every time the function runs, making it impossible to use this function in parallel with itself. A simpler way would be to pass in a buffer from the `caller`, rather than create it in the `callee`, and change the return type to `void`. That's one example of something that could be improved.

Comment: Rather than magic number 64, use a value to handle all `double`.  Perhaps : `result[DBL_MAX_10_EXP*4/3 + 7];`

Comment: `strmoney(-123.45)` --> `"- 123.45"`. `"-123.45"` expected.

Answer (score 2):

A secure way to format thousand separators, with support for negative numbers:

Because VS < 2015 doesn't implement snprintf, you need to do this

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
    #define snprintf(buf,len, format,...) _snprintf_s(buf, len,len, format, __VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

And then

```
char* format_commas(int n, char *out)
{
    int c;
    char buf[100];
    char *p;
    char* q = out; // Backup pointer for return...

    if (n < 0)
    {
        *out++ = '-';
        n = abs(n);
    }


    snprintf(buf, 100, "%d", n);
    c = 2 - strlen(buf) % 3;

    for (p = buf; *p != 0; p++) {
        *out++ = *p;
        if (c == 1) {
            *out++ = '\'';
        }
        c = (c + 1) % 3;
    }
    *--out = 0;

    return q;
}
```

Example usage:

```
size_t currentSize = getCurrentRSS();
size_t peakSize = getPeakRSS();


printf("Current size: %d\n", currentSize);
printf("Peak size: %d\n\n\n", peakSize);

char* szcurrentSize = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
char* szpeakSize = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

printf("Current size (f): %s\n", format_commas((int)currentSize, szcurrentSize));
printf("Peak size (f): %s\n", format_commas((int)currentSize, szpeakSize));

free(szcurrentSize);
free(szpeakSize);
```

Comment: Fails for `format_commas(INT_MIN, buf));` Sample: `"--2'147'483'648"`.  `abs(INT_MIN)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Rather than `strlen(buf)`, code could use the return value of `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 2):

My own version for unsigned int64:

```
char* toString_DigitGrouping( unsigned __int64 val )
{
    static char result[ 128 ];
    _snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%lld", val);

    size_t i = strlen(result) - 1;
    size_t i2 = i + (i / 3);
    int c = 0;
    result[i2 + 1] = 0;

    for( ; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        result[i2--] = result[i];
        c++;
        if( c % 3 == 0 )
            result[i2--] = '\'';
    } //for

    return result;  
} //toString_DigitGrouping
```

Comment: `"%lld"` is not the same sign-ness as `unsigned __int64`.  I recommend to use a match format specifier and type.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[50];
    int len = 0;   
    scanf("%48[^\n]%n", str, &len);

    int start = len % 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {        
        if(i == start && i != 0) {
            printf(" ");
        } else if((i - start) % 3 == 0 && i != 0) {
            printf(" ");
        }    
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }   

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Input `-123` outputs `- 123`.  I'd expect output `-123`.

Comment: Try it:

https://pastebin.com/raw/Y6vRfRuz

Comment: What do you get with input "-123456"?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void punt(int n){
    char s[28];
    int i = 27;
    if(n<0){n=-n; putchar('-');} 
    do{
        s[i--] = n%10 + '0';
        if(!(i%4) && n>9)s[i--]=' ';
        n /= 10;
    }while(n);
    puts(&s[++i]);
}


int main(){

    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    punt(a);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *commify(char *numstr){
    char *wk, *wks, *p, *ret=numstr;
    int i;

    wks=wk=strrev(strdup(numstr));
    p = strchr(wk, '.');
    if(p){//include '.' 
        while(wk != p)//skip until '.'
            *numstr++ = *wk++;
        *numstr++=*wk++;
    }
    for(i=1;*wk;++i){
        if(isdigit(*wk)){
            *numstr++=*wk++;
            if(isdigit(*wk) && i % 3 == 0)
                *numstr++ = ',';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    while(*numstr++=*wk++);

    free(wks); 
    return strrev(ret);
}


int main(){
    char buff[64];//To provide a sufficient size after conversion.
    sprintf(buff, "%d", 100);
    printf("%s\n", commify(buff));
    sprintf(buff, "%d", 123456);
    printf("%s\n", commify(buff));
    sprintf(buff, "%.2f", 1234.56f);
    printf("%s\n", commify(buff));
    sprintf(buff, "%d", -123456);
    printf("%s\n", commify(buff));
    sprintf(buff, "%.2lf", -12345678.99);
    printf("%s\n", commify(buff));
    return 0;
}
```

ADD:

```
/*
char *strrev(char *str){
    char c,*front,*back;

    for(front=str,back=str+strlen(str)-1;front < back;front++,back--){
        c=*front;*front=*back;*back=c;
    }
    return(str);
}
*/
```

Comment: implementation of the printf option is not supported in many compilers, no choice but to implement it yourself.

Comment: `strrev` is unavailable on some compilers but can be implemented as in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534274/is-strrev-function-not-available-in-linux . With it, the code gave me the correct answers, so I've nullified someone's downvote. Thanks, BLUEPIXY.