# format number in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

How to format a number 1234567 into  1,234,567   in C#?

Comment: There are already enough answers to this question, folks. You can stop posting new ones. Feel free to delete exact duplicates.

Answer (score 29):

For format options for [Int32.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring), see [standard format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) or [custom format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

For example:

```
string s = myIntValue.ToString("#,##0");
```

The same format options can be use in a String.Format, as in

```
string s = String.Format("the number {0:#,##0}!", myIntValue);
```

Do note that the `,` in that format doesn't specify a "use a *comma*" but rather that the grouping character for the current culture should be used, in the culture-specific positions.

You also do not need to specify a comma for every position. The fact that there is a comma in the format string means that the culture-specific grouping is used.

So you get "1 234 567 890" for pl-PL or "1,23,45,67,890" for hi-IN.

Answer (score 8):

```
var decimalValue = 1234567m; 
var value =  String.Format("{0:N}", decimalValue); // 1,234,567.00
```

or without cents

```
var value =  String.Format("{0:N0}", decimalValue); // 1,234,567
```

Answer (score 6):

Try 
    String.Format("{0:##,####,####}", 8958712551)

For Examples have a look at http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 6):

Using your current locale's thousands separator:

```
int n = 1234567 ;
n.ToString("N0");
```

Or, use the overload to ToString, which takes the culture as a parameter.

Comment: This is what I have been using but now need to know if it rounds or just removes decimals when encountered and having trouble finding an answer. Do you know which it is and if so which is it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
string formatted = string.Format("{0:##,#}", 123456789);
```

It depends on the culture of your computer. Some countries use commas, some countries use dots. On my computer the output was: 123.456.789