# WPF Regional Settings decimal separator

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, decimal

Is there any way to use regional settings decimal separator in text boxes with binding StringFormat={}{0:N2} without handling the keydown or keypreview or whatever events?

It seems very trivial for me, but I can't figure out why it's so complicated to have a text box handling decimals correctly...

I know there is a lot of discussions on that subject, I won't accept to handle the keyX events... I don't want to create yet another control that do this for me while it should already exists...

Thanks,

**Edit**

Some precision : I want the textbox to know what decimal separator to use when typing Key.Decimal or Key.OemPeriod

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the ConverterCulture in the binding?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding value, StringFormat=N2, ConverterCulture=de}" />
```

Comment: I don't really understand the use of this property, but it's not working... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterculture(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: In this way will be used the separator (and the other format settings) of the culture specified in ConverterCulture

Answer (score 0):

this separates only decimals

```
textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}",Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text));
```

[format number in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954777/format-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: My problem is when I want the text box to know what decimal separator to use when typing Key.OemPeriod or Key.Decimal