# How to format a string of numbers "12345678" to "1,23,45,678"

Tags: c#, .net, string, format

I need to format my number like
123456 to 1,23,456
1234567 to 12,34,567
12345678 to 1,23,45,678
123456789 to 12,34,56,789

Comment: no sir, basically all of format show only 3 digit separate comma, but I need 3 and 2 both digit comma

Comment: Take a look at this thread, i believe this will help. [number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954777/format-number-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [format number in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954777/format-number-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for conversion to Indian counting format.

Use the below code to format the string

`string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN"), "{0:#,#}", number)`

Using the above code the output of inputted number would be

```
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN"), "{0:#,#}", 123456)
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN"), "{0:#,#}", 1234567)
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN"), "{0:#,#}", 12345678)


1,23,456


12,34,567


1,23,45,678
```

Check this dotnet fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/TXQ09n