# How to convert 26750 string to 26,750 format in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Hi Guys,

I have got **26750** in my string variable, something like below:

```
string str = "26750";
```

Now before showing on page, I want it to be converted into `"26,750"` format using c#. This value can increase as well as decrease also according to the result, so my format should work in both the cases.

Please suggest!

EDIT:

As I have written I have got string type value in my variable, I am trying with below code, but it is not working for me.

```
spnMiles.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0:n}", Miles);
```

It is not changing to the number format.

Please suggest!

Comment: Bear in mind, not everyone uses , for a thousand separator. If your program will be used internationally, you need to look into globalization.

Comment: thanks @Flyn, I am looking for such implementation, please suggest

Comment: Do you want to add a comma, or the locale dependent thousand-separator?

Comment: Pass `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` as an `IFormatProvider` parameter to `string.Format`. Review the intellisense/Object Browser in VS for more info.

Comment: Guys I have edit my question and added my sample code, please see and suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should answers yours:

[.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: can I have example code for my problem?

Comment: @MKS if you want to learn to program you shouldn't let people spoon feed you. Try to figure it out first.

Comment: The suggested duplicate has a subtle difference and is not quite the question asked because this question asks to format a string that is a number and the duplicate answer formats a numerical value which does not work on a string.  The solution is to parse the string as a numeric before formatting.  For example: string sTotal = "19032"; int iTotal = 0; int.TryParse(sTotal, out iTotal); string.Format("{0:n0}", iTotal); will give 19,032 as the output.