# C# String Format

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Hello

I have money value like that

```
    12345
    123456
    1234567
    1234567,89
```

What i want is formated like this.

```
12,345
123,456
1,234,567
1,234,567, 89
```

How can i do that with [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: Please correct the last case as .89

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:c}");
```

This will format your number like currency based on the client's locale configuration.

If your client's locale is in Europe it'll come out $12.134,45 because that's how it's done over there.

This is the preferred method of currency formatting, if you want to specifically just get the comma's and no $ you'll probably have to do it using "{0:#,##0}" or something along those lines.

Comment: +1. Usual reminder - there are cultures that don't have groups separator too. If you explicitly need format with , as "groups separator" pass specific culture (i.e. "en-US" to String.Format).

Answer (score 1):

[Cool new way...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator.aspx)