# Add comma to numbers every three digits using C#

Tags: c#

I want to add comma to decimal numbers every 3 digits using c#.
I wrote this code :

```
double a = 0; 
a = 1.5;
Interaction.MsgBox(string.Format("{0:#,###0}", a));
```

But it returns 2.
Where am I wrong ?
Please describe how can I fix it ?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: @raj: the answers here are different.

Comment: @GregC Though, not necessarily better ones [than the one that's accepted there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/105793/1028230). ;^)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 double a = 1.5;
Interaction.MsgBox(string.Format("{0:#,###0.#}", a));
```

Comment: It is right thank you ,would you please describe about first argument of string.Format ?

Comment: In your format string you weren't addressing the decimal part of the number so it was rounding it off to 2.  So the .# In the format string addresses that and if always want decimal part to be displayed, even for, say 2.0 then use .0 in the format string.

Comment: I have a question: is the format in the answer is different from `#,0.#`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it:

```
 string.Format("{0:0,0.0}", a)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) that will separate thousand units: `N`

```
float value = 1234.512;

value.ToString("N"); // 1,234.512
String.Format("N2", value); // 1,234.51
```

Answer (score 2):

Its doing it right. #,##0 means write at least one digit and zero decimals and space digit groups with comas. Therefore it rounds 1.5 to 2 as it cant write decimals. Try #,##0.00 instead. You'll get 1.50

Answer (score 2):

Try the following format:

```
string.Format("{0:#,0.0}", a)
```

Comment: It works , but for number 10 it returns 10.0 , should i replace 10.0 with nothing or it is possible to improve string.Format function ?

Comment: @shaahin, string formats for doubles are nicely explained in [this article](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/). As far as 10.0 is concerned if you don't want the decimal if it is 0 you could use `{0:#,#.#}`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried by this:-

```
string.Format("{0:0,000.0}", 1.5);
```