# place a comma after each 3 digit in a 9 digit numbe in c#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)
>   [Add comma to numbers every three digits using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161254/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-c)

I want to create a logic in c# too put the comma after each 3 digit int the any 9 digit number, could any body tel me how can i achieve this?

Like i have the following number 123456789 then i want to form it like 123,456,789.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: Check ToString() and String.Format

Comment: not predefined function..som god logic i awnt.

Answer (score 1):

Call ToString and specify "N" as the [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var formattedString = string.Format("{0:0,0}", 123456789);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```