# for loop  formatting  mvc3

Tags: c#, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

I have an `int` that is passed through to the a view and it need to formatting so it is not one big block of number. e.g

```
0
00
000
000,0
000,000
000,000,000
```

How can i do this using a for loop?

thanks

Comment: what is the criteria for formatting? Will it be formatted the same way every time? What is the format?

Comment: formatted so every three number a comma is inserted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Answer (score 0):

You may want to output the integer as `i.ToString("###,###,###");`

However, this would not display a value if the int is 0.

You could try using System.Drawing.Color to represent the colour value rather than an int.  This has a method ToArgb()