# Add Thousand Separator To A Double Value(Control Decimals, Remove Zero Decimals)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, double, string.format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

i have a double value that i want to add it thousand separator, with below conditions :
1- remove zero decimals after dor(.)
2-control count of decimals

for example :

```
string str_Money = Convert.ToDouble(Money).ToString("N3");
```

this code for Money = 50000 returns 50,000.000, but i don't want zero decimals(mean i want 50,000)
another example : for Money = 50000.2355 returns 50,000.235 and that is exactly what i want
how can i reformat it?

Comment: So, you want the thousands separator, but nothing following the decimal point ever (i.e. round)?  Or only put two digits after decimal point if one is non-zero?  I'm confused.

Comment: thanks for the link, but it's not duplicate!

Comment: Money and `Double` in one sentence is a huge red flag. Use `Decimal` to represent money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the accepted answer from [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number), use an if statement to control to returned format.

```
string str_Money = "";
if (money % != 0) // test for decimals
{
    str_Money = string.Format("{0:n0}", money); // no decimals.
}
else
{
    str_Money = string.Format("{0:n}", money);
}
```

Comment: The format can be selected using `?:` within the `Format`: `string.Format(money % 1 <> 0 ? "{0:n0}" : "{0:n}", money)`.

Comment: hi, what is this <> sign in c#?

Comment: My bad, I still type other language syntax sometimes. It should be !=