# How do I format numerical data as thousands in a GridView Column ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview with columns like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblHM1" Text="Hm1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblM1" Text='<%# Eval("m1","{0:#0}")%>' runat="server">
          </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The numbers in this column are often greater than 1000, so I'd like to format them as such.  For example, if the data in this column reads `11359`, I'd like it to format the number as `11,359`.

I have attempted the following:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblHM1" Text="Hm1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblM1" Text='<%# Eval("m1","{0:N0}")%>' runat="server">
          </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But the above generates an exception:  `Input string was not in a correct format`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblM1" Text='<%# Eval("m1","{0:0,0}")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

That should format 11239 as "11.239". The Group Separator would be different depending on your culture.

Take a look to the documentation:

[The , custom specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierTh)

and

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

EDIT:
By the way, it could be a completely different reason. It could be that you're sending the data in one culture, but .Net it's trying to parse with a different one that's not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your format and it worked for me, thanks :)

just change as follow and try if it works for u.

'>

instead of Eval use DataBinder.EVal.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this-

```
Text='<%# Eval("m1","{0:0,0}") %>'
```