# How to change display format of long variable?

Tags: c#

I have a variable of type Long i.e.

```
long quantity=1000;
```

I want to display it like `1,000` in Grid (Must need commas)

How do i achieve this?

I am using a Telerik Grid and I am binding the data as follows:

```
columns.Bound(tempProductList => tempProductList.tempProductListQuantity) .Title("Quantity")
```

Comment: What Grid exactly? Show the relevant code.

Comment: @Jon, its Telerik Grid. Here is my sample code for Telerik Grid  columns.Bound(tempProductList => tempProductList.tempProductListQuantity)
                   .Title("Quantity")

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: Do you want to force the comma irrespective of culture? Or do you want it to display the correct character for the current culture? e.g. `en-US = "1,234"` and `fr-CH = "1'234"`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) you have a list of all the standard numeric formats. I think "N" is the one you want.

```
long l = 1234;
string s  = l.ToString("N0"); //gives "1,234"
```

The "0" after the format specifier is the number of desired decimal places (usually 2 by default).

Note that this version is culture-sensitive, i.e., in my country, we use dots (".") as thousand separators, so the actual returned value will be "1.234" instead of the "1,234". If this is desired behaviour, just leave it as is, but if you need to use commas always, then you should specify a culture as a parameter to the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tdw2bzc.aspx) method, like

```
l.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //always return "1,234"
```

Comment: He wants commans as thousand separator. Half of the world uses dots as thousand separator.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That is not confirmed, the OP may just not understand that other cultures use other characters

Comment: @TimSchmelter added a culture info explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Custom Culture that will allow you to specify the thousand separator.

From [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27053/Culture-Specific-Number-Formatting-in-ASP-NET):

```
//Create first the format provider the String.Format 
//will use to format our string
CultureInfo cultureToUse = new CultureInfo("fi-FI");
Console.WriteLine("Using the following CultureInfor " + 
                  cultureToUse.Name);

//Now practice some decimal numbers 
//Here we override the culture specific formattings
cultureToUse.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 3;
cultureToUse.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 3;
cultureToUse.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
cultureToUse.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "euro";
cultureToUse.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
```

Next you would need to use this culture when formatting the numbers. 
You could do the formattin gby hand but you could also assign the culture to the Current(UI)Culture property of the current thread.

Comment: Why go through all this trouble when you can just specify the format in the `ToString` function?

Comment: This is a nice global solution if you need to change **all** number formating in one fell swoop.

Comment: Also, this doesn't even answer the question. All it shows is how to create a CultureInfo, you do not demonstrate applying it anywhere, which is the key factor. Especially considering there will already be a default culture info set which will use some sort of thousands separator anyway.. sorry, have to vote you down at the minute

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider the international point of view, there will not be always commas before the decimal part. ToString function will give you what you want.

(1000.0).ToString("N",new CultureInfo("en-US")) = 1,000.00

(1000.0).ToString("N",new CultureInfo("is-IS")) = 1.000,00