# How to format a string with thousands separation and decimal comma?

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting, string-formatting

I have some strings:

```
string amount = "123456";
string amount2 = "123456.78";
```

I want the output to be:

```
amount: 123.456,00
amount2: 123.456,78
```

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number), but this does not work for my example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
decimal.Parse(amount).ToString("N")
```

This assumes your culture uses the format you want. You can specify a culture explicitly, for example:

```
decimal.Parse(amount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("N", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

for the culture "German (Germany)" (`"de-DE"`). Edited to specify format provider for the `Parse` method as well.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I solved the problem with:

```
string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", Convert.ToDouble(amount))
```

Comment: This of course is equivalent to `Convert.ToDouble(amount).ToString("0,0.00")`. But as I said in my answer, `"N"` can also be used instead of `"0,0.00"` (or `"N2"` in the rare occasion where the culture has `NumberDecimalDigits` distinct from `2`).

Answer (score 1):

Alternativly, the following also enables easy user-customization what was a requirement for my app.

```
string groupSeperator = ".";
string decimalSeperator = ",";
int decimalDigits= 2;

decimal.Parse(amount).ToString("N", new NumberFormatInfo{NumberDecimalSeparator = decimalSeperator , NumberDecimalDigits = decimalDigits, NumberGroupSeparator = groupSeperator});
```

Comment: Perfect snippet solution !!! copy paste --> works !

You are great !!!
We can really define or customize the number format as wished.  

For me it was like:                    
            string groupSeperator = "'";
            string decimalSeperator = ".";
            int decimalDigits = 0;

            var s_TotalWordCount = m_TotalWordCount.ToString("N", new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = decimalSeperator, NumberDecimalDigits = decimalDigits, NumberGroupSeparator = groupSeperator });