# Format a number to display a comma when larger than a thousand

Tags: vb.net, string, long-integer, number-formatting, tryparse

I am writing some code in Visual Basic.net and have a question.

If I have a long number, that is larger than 1000, how can I format this value to be 1,000 (with a comma) and for this to be stored in a string?

For e.g.

1234 will be stored as 1,234
12345 will be stored as 12,345
123456 will be stored as 123,456

Is this done with a TryParse statement?

May I have some help to so this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Take a look at [The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

General use:

```
Dim dblValue As Double = -12445.6789
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
' Displays -12,445.68
```

If you are only using integers then the following:

```
Dim numberString As String = 1234.ToString("N0")
```

Will show `numberString = "1,234"` as the `"N0"` format will not add any figures after a decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

For those wanting to do a currency with commas and decimals use the following: .ToString("$0,00.00")

Answer (score 1):

Using `$` notation:

```
int myvar = 12345;    
Console.WriteLine($"Here is my number: {myvar:N0}");
```