# C# formatting number

Tags: c#, formatting

I need one C# formatting string that will handle those cases:

For input of `1234.561` should produce: `1,234.56`

For input of `1234` should produce: `1,234`

I tried `{0:N0}`, `{0:N2}` and `{0:#.##}`. Doesn't work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number. Make sure the input is decimal/float or integer but NOT string!

Comment: Have seen this thread. Cant find anything that will fit the bill there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.

{0:#,#.##}

Answer (score 0):

```
string stringNumber = number.ToString("#,##0");
```

Comment: procudes 1,234 i need 1,234.56

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "{0:F2}"? <strike>I don't think you can use the "#" as pattern.</strike>

UPDATE: I was wrong. The "#" is allowed as custom placeholder.

Comment: Produces 1239.00 I need 1,239