# Simple editing comma needed for the dollar amt

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Here in this column I want to show $1234.56 as $1,234.56.

How do I modify $0.00 to do this?

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="30DayCost" 
                           Caption="30DayCost" 
                           VisibleIndex="9" Width="100px">
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></CellStyle>
    <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="$0.00"></PropertiesTextEdit>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: please remove the negative vote, this is a coding question from a newbie. come on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `DisplayFormatString` format from `$0.00` to `$#,##0.00`.

Comment: What about cultures which have a different thousands separator?

Comment: @jdphenix: both the thousands and the decimal separator will be adjusted to the culture. See http://ideone.com/LMcTfR for a sample for de-DE.