# Formatting a number to a customized format in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, numbers, decimal

I have value in `133354.4` format but I want this as `133, 354.40`
format only.

I don't know how to convert this using **c#**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: @user3432842.. look at globalization format i have given below

Comment: Do you need comma *and* space? If yes you'll need to build custom CultureInfo for that as I don't think there is one with `", "` as separator.

Comment: Side note: please update title to something that explain what you need. "help me with this" is not very helpful for future readers. And check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) about thank you notes.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use customized formatting ([More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierTh)) which is available in `Globalization`

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double value = 133354.4;
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    }
}
```

### output:

> 133,354.40

Comment: This really helped a lot but in zero, it displays like this '.00'. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, convert it to `decimal`, for sample:

```
string number = "133354.4";

decimal value = decimal.Parse(number);

string formatedNumber = value.ToString("N");
```

[`ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method from [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type, has a format type you can specify the type of number you want to print. Look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add the specific type you need.