# How to insert a comma to left after every 3 digits and show 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to insert a comma to left after every 3 digits and show 2 decimal places in c# but using String.Format

Thanks.

Comment: What does javascript have to do with this?

Comment: have you checked `N2` in [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) `intValue.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/ This is my go to cheat sheet.

Answer (score 4):

```
        string a = string.Format("{0:n}", 1234567.123);
```

result would be 1,234,567.12

Answer (score 3):

Try this, though i just copied it from another question here in SO

```
String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", MyNumber)
```

Refer to this link: [StringFormat int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please accept my answer if it solves your problem, here's the info you need: How to accept an answer. Please also consider to upvote my answer when you have enough reputation to do so. @Naveen Sharma

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old. The new way of doing is using string interpolation as:

```cs
var value = 1234567890.106;
Console.WriteLine($"{value:n}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

int number = 10000000000;
string whatYouWant = number.ToString("##,##0");

//You get: 10,000,000,000

Answer (score 0):

```
        var value = 1234567890.106;
        Console.WriteLine( String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            "{0:#,#.##}", value ) );
```

Refer to this in the future:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD