# C# format float to string with separators and padding 0

Tags: c#, formatting, number-formatting

I need to format ints and floats to string.

If it's float, I need `,` to be decimal separator. And `.` must be thousand separator.

Also, I need to complete remaining decimals with `0`. Some examples:

```
float:
45,3: 000.045,30
125: 000.125,00
83560.195: 083.560,19

int:
45: 000.045
5789: 005.789
```

I managed to format thousands with `"{0:#,0}"` but I still can't find how to format decimals and how to properly pad keeping separators.

This must be done regardless of configured culture :/

Comment: Have you tried googling this ..? there are a lot of different ways to do this.. here is a previous `SO` posting that can give you many answers hints and a direction that you can take. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: I think you should use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys. I was googling it and was able to learn part of the solution, but was unable to find the part I asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works with the given examples:

```
NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator=",",
    NumberGroupSeparator="."
};

string formatFloat(float f)
{
    return f.ToString("0####,0.00",numberFormat);
}

string formatInt(int i)
{
    return i.ToString("0####,0",numberFormat);
}
```

Comment: Good solution, and looks independent on current culture. If one wants to reuse the format info object, one can use `static readonly NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = NumberFormatInfo.ReadOnly(new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", NumberGroupSeparator = ".", });` to be on the very safe side.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the culture to a European culture, and format:

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:000,000.00}", num).Dump();
```