# how to format only the integer part from the decimal number

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose there is a number like

```
333987.67
```

I want to format only the integer part irrespective of decimal part, how long the decimal part will be it can be upto 10 digit also
Like

```
333,987.67
```

No rounding nothing.
How to do that? Do i have to split the decimal and integer part using "."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: You tostring using the correct format https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format` Below is the example

```
String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", 400000)
```

output is:      "4,00,000.00"

Here is the MSDN [link](http://goo.gl/AANqYN)

Comment: 5689.6786543. By using your example it will return 5,689.68. I want 5,689.6786543

Comment: You need to increase the '0' after decimal to get the exact precision.       ex:String.Format("{0:#,##0.0000000000}", 5689.6786543). Or take only integer part of the number and work on it.