# How to group digits in a number with separators?

Tags: c#

I need to show the amount value seperated by `,`

For example, my textbox vaue is 614000 and I would like to show in in a textbox like `6,14,000`

I wrote the following code

```
double result = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1_newww.Rows)
{
    result += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Total_Cost"].Value);
}
textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

but i will not separate directly shows join  value = 614000

Comment: `6,14,000` is not a proper representation for a cost value. Is your pattern always should be as `X,XX,XXX`?

Comment: Have a look at this similar stackoverflow question, it shows the formating options available [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: Please give your question a proper title, I tried to edit it a little bit to make it a bit clearer but its still unclear what you are asking, How is the code you provided currently supposed to do custom formatting?

Comment: My textbox values shows=614000 but i need or show like 6,14,000 because this is amount

Comment: Well yes, it would do. that sounds like the default formatting is working. What have you researched to solve your problem? There are plenty of resources around for formatting numbers..

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", result)
```

this  will give you commas at the relevant points.