# How to add comma in random generated numbers C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = (new Random().NextDouble() * (new Random()).Next(10000)).ToString("0.00");
    //if (this.label1.Text.Length >= 7)
    //{
    //    this.label1.Text = string.Format("{0:0,0}", label1.Text);
    //}
}
```

which generated random number from `1-10000`. I want to insert comma like this: `9,677.89`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:N2}", new Random().NextDouble()*10000)
```

Comment: Whenever using this code please make sure to specify culture to get required result (unless you live in US).

Comment: Is the multiplication with larger integer and later division by double necessary? NextDouble already return double and "If one of the operands in a mathematical operation is a numeric type other than a Double, it is converted to a Double before performing the operation. The result of the operation is also a Double value. " https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Duplicate lists several variants that one can use - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668208/477420 if you need the same separators all the time - use invariant, if need particular one - specify explicitly, or use current as your code shows .