# MVC Entity Framework Integer Thousand Separator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, displayformat

This is probably a very simple question but i cannot work it out and i cannot find it anywhere.

I have a model with the following property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:0.##}")]
public decimal Jan { get; set; }
```

As you can see, it is a simple decimal value which I have used the DisplayFormat annotation on in order to remove the decimal places, if the decimal places are .00.

However, I now need to edit this DisplayFormat in order to include thousand and million separators as commas.

Does anybody know how i would go about this please?

Many Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
public decimal Jan { get; set; }
```

Comment: Wont this do just the thousand seperator and not maintain my decimal place format? do you know how i would combine the two?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your doing this quite right. Check out this article on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688127.aspx.  Specifically the section "Number Formatting in .net."  Currency formatting is a localization concern.  You want to use the currency formatting of .net to give you the correct separators

Comment: This is not currency though. It is just standard numbers so there should be a way for me to do it as i have done the decimal places as there is no localization issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: I found that question also, however, i couldnt work out how to combine it with my other DisplayFormat. any ideas?