# How to convert int to a decimal with comma?

Tags: c#

```
        Console.Write("Hoeveel worpen wil je simuleren: ");
        int worpen = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



        Random r = new Random(worpen);
        int willekeur = r.Next(1, worpen);
        double willekeur1 = willekeur;
        Math.Round(willekeur1);


        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ik gooide "+willekeur+" ("+Math.Round(willekeur1,2,)+")"); 
            willekeur = r.Next(1, worpen);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I want that ' willekeur1 ' a  number which contains a decimal comma is. so example: 12456--> 12,456

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: `Int`s don't have decimals or commas - when you convert to a string, the current culture (or a culture you specify) determines the format. Use [`string.Format(number, format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`double.ToString(format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the format you want the result in.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking (especially with something completely unrelated accepted as answer). Maybe you just looking for `willekeur1/1000.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do: (you need latest c# to use string interpolation)

```
 $"{12456:n0}"; // 12,456
 $"{12456:n2}"; // 12,456.00
```

In your case

```
Console.WriteLine($"ik gooide {willekeur} ({Math.Round(willekeur1,2,)})");
```

or

```
 $"{Math.Round(willekeur1,2):n0}"; 
 $"{Math.Round(willekeur1,2):n2}";
```

Answer (score -1):

this might be useful for you:

```
public float ReadFloat()
        {
            float ReadValue = 0;
            string KeySequence = "";
            string TempKey = "";
            bool CommaUsed = false;
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;
            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if ((key.Key >= ConsoleKey.D0 && key.Key <= ConsoleKey.D9) || (key.Key >= ConsoleKey.NumPad0 && key.Key <= ConsoleKey.NumPad9))
                {
                    TempKey = Convert.ToString(key.Key);
                    TempKey = TempKey.Remove(0, 1);
                    KeySequence += TempKey;
                    Console.Write(TempKey);
                };

                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.OemComma || key.Key == ConsoleKey.Decimal)
                {
                    if (!CommaUsed)
                    {
                        KeySequence += ".";
                        Console.Write(".");
                        CommaUsed = true;

                    };
                };

                if ((key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace) && KeySequence != "")
                {
                    string LastChar = KeySequence.Substring(KeySequence.Length - 1);
                    //MessageBox.Show("Last char: "+LastChar);
                    //Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)
                    char SepDeci = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
                    if (Convert.ToChar(LastChar) == SepDeci)
                    {
                        CommaUsed = false;
                    };
                    KeySequence = KeySequence.Remove(KeySequence.Length - 1);
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                };
            }
            while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
            if (KeySequence == "")
            {
                return 0;
            };
            ReadValue = Convert.ToSingle(KeySequence);
            return ReadValue;
        }
```

this method reads value from console but allows only numbers and one decimal separator (comma or dot, depending on your culture settings).
to use is to read value to a variable:

```
willekeur1 = ReadFloat();
```

Comment: This post does not look like it provides an answer to question asked. Also it is very strange to propose manual code to parse numbers when built in functions exist for parsing and formatting...