# Converting int to string with a specific format

Tags: c#, string, winforms, integer

I'm trying to convert an classical integer value like:

```
2000
```

into a format like this:

```
2.000,00
```

I have tried the following methods:

```
String.valueOf(input.format());
```

And this method:

```
private String getCents(Decimal x){
    String y = String.valueOf(x);
    String z = '.';
    if(y.contains(',')) z = ',';
    y = y.substring(0, y.indexOf(z));
    if(x - Decimal.valueOf(y) == 0)
        return String.valueOf(x.format()) + z + '00';
    else return String.valueOf(x.format());
}
```

But the string class doesn't contains the valueOf method for some reason. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: This question has an established answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking for  C#? What you've found is java

Comment: @TimSchmelter oops I thought the string class in c# might have the same method like the one in Java... ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `String` does not contain the method `valueOf`, because this ain't Java, you know.
The method you are searching for is `ToString`, which allows a format-provider as an argument. The simplest way is another string which defines the format.

```
    int i = 2000;
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("#,##0.00"));
    Console.ReadLine();
```

This will do what you want to do.
Read more about format-providers in the docs of the `ToString`method.

Comment: would this imply for bigger numbers than 2000 ? like 20000 ? 20.000,00 ?

Comment: Yes, as said, read about providers on msdn. My example makes sure that digit froups are delimited by a comma and that there is a 0, when passing values < 1

Answer (score 1):

given en-US culture
this will do:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N}", 2000)
```

Comment: One moment i'll try your solution