# c# How to separate an int with decimal points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, format, tostring, separator

I am trying to format an int with decimal points as separators, not commas.

Example: **1234567890** should be formatted to **1.234.567.890**

```
text_team1.text = em.team1Score.ToString("#,##0");
```

This will give **1,234,567,890**

However in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number) there was some information about using the class CultureInfo which contains the format-style, so I used several of them:

```
text_team1.text = em.team1Score.ToString("#,##0", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("IS-is"));
```

as an example. But it seems that every cultureInfo uses a comma as separator.

Even by editing the string afterwards, there is still the comma as seperator.

```
text_team1.text = em.team1Score.ToString("#,##0");
text_team1.text.Replace(',','.');
```

Comment: The globalized approach varies by .... culture. Some places use spaces for separators (`1 234 567 890)`, others use commas (`1,234,567,890`), others do different things. The globalize approach should only be used if you want to show the use a number in their native format. If you're doing something custom (e.g., a dot seperated ip address), you should not use it. It seems that you're trying to show the score to a user, so you should use their native format by using the globalized string.

Comment: Interestingly, CultureInfo "IS-is" does use the decimal separator in dotnetfiddle. Here's an example https://dotnetfiddle.net/KqCmlv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even by editing the string afterwards, there is still the comma as
>   seperator.
>
> ```
> text_team1.text = em.team1Score.ToString("#,##0");
> text_team1.text.Replace(',','.');
> ```

You forgot to assign the replaced string back.

```
text_team1.text = text_team1.text.Replace(',','.');
```

**EDIT**:

If you still prefer a solution without using the `Replace` function, you can use the Extension method below. It works for `strings` and `ints`. Please Google and read about extension methods if you don't know how they work.

*Create and place the `ExtensionMethod` script in any folder in your project*:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System;

public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string formatStringWithDot(this string stringToFormat)
    {
        string convertResult = "";
        int tempInt;
        if (Int32.TryParse(stringToFormat, out tempInt))
        {
            convertResult = tempInt.ToString("N0", new NumberFormatInfo()
            {
                NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 3 },
                NumberGroupSeparator = "."
            });
        }
        return convertResult;
    }

    public static string formatStringWithDot(this int intToFormat)
    {
        string convertResult = "";

        convertResult = intToFormat.ToString("N0", new NumberFormatInfo()
        {
            NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 3 },
            NumberGroupSeparator = "."
        });
        return convertResult;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
string stringToFormat = "1234567890";
Debug.Log(stringToFormat.formatStringWithDot());
```

Or

```
int intToFormat = 1234567890;
Debug.Log(intToFormat.formatStringWithDot());
```

Or

```
string stringToFormat = "1234567890";
text_team1.text = stringToFormat.formatStringWithDot();
```

Use each one depending on which scenario you run into.

Comment: What a fail! Thank you! __text_team1.text = em.team1Score.ToString("#,##0").Replace(',','.')__ much shorter :D

Answer (score 2):

If you are using globalisation as a means to format your string, you could set a [Custom Group Seperator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;

// Displays the same value with a blank as the separator.
Int64 myInt = 1234567890;
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N0", nfi ) );
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vRqd6x

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7(v=vs.110).aspx).
Does your OS represent numbers with that format? If so, you can try with [the simplest form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
text_team1.text = string.Format("{0:N}", em.team1Score);
```

or you can force it with

```
text_team1.text = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("IS-is"), "{0:N}", em.team1Score);
```

which cares of the culture.