# How to format a number 1000 to 1,000 for textbox to use in a Tostring in C# in a label and in a message.show

Tags: c#, textbox, messagebox

How to format a number 1000 to 1,000 for `textbox` to use in a `Tostring` in C#
in a label and in a `message.show`

myString = "Attempt #" + AttemptNumber.ToString( );

AttemptsLbl.Text = AttemptNumber.ToString();

MessageBox.Show(" Match Found for All 3 Digits - it took " + AttemptNumber + " tries!");

Comment: i hope i asked the right question idk even how to ask even tough i look online and read im kinda confuse how to ask or criteria programming is new to me

Comment: thank you @bc004346 for editing im new to this how long have you code and how long does it take to be kinda knowledgeable about code i know i'm broad and general budi idk how to ask ?

Comment: I've been at it for 15 years or so and I still have a lot to learn. But I do it for a living. To learn a specific language, a couple weeks. You should really learn and understand object oriented programming, and best practices to be effective. Then you can apply your knowledge with any language. Really, a couple years should do it :) Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much i wanna build apps and i 'm doing c# right now but going to to go to android programming i wanna do this for a living and build or make apps for companies and myself :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this format `#,##0`, which can be used in either `ToString` or `String.Format`. When inserting the number in the middle of a string, I find `String.Format` more convenient. Both examples below.

```
myString = String.Format("Attempt #{0:#,##0}", AttemptNumber);
AttemptsLbl.Text = AttemptNumber.ToString("#,##0");
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Match Found for All 3 Digits - it took {0:#,##0} tries!", AttemptNumber));
```

The format string from this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/295821/832052

Comment: You guys are awsome  djv /Jim Simson

Comment: how many years of practice do you need to be good at coding @djv i know this is broad and general but idk how else to ask

Comment: The answer is 42.

Answer (score 1):

Johnyc,
You can use `MyString = n.ToString("###,###");` for that.

Comment: Thank you so much both you guys helped  me alot :)) @ Jim Simson

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: how many years does it take to be good at coding Jim Simson like to be able to know undesrtand it good idk i know it broad and general but idk how else to ask