# String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number not working

Tags: c#

`String.Format` to add commas in thousands place just add space without comma.

I tried:

```
 var total = string.Format("{0:n0}", 12345);
 // expect: total = 12,345
 // actual: total = 12 345
```

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: You missed updating your SO profile so we can tell where you live.  The exact formatting is culture-specific and can be overridden with Control Panel.  Consider using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat if you insist on commas.

Comment: It depends on your current culture settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a culture thing. In your locale, space is the thousands specifier, apparently. I see commas. To see a *specific* locale's output, specify that explicitly. A very common option is "invariant":

```
var total = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:n0}", 12345);
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be your regional settings on you PC:

[image]

The [**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Le6dj) works fine