# Changing a Int to a String then Formatting the String

Tags: c#, html, string, visual-studio, int

`<p class="card"> Credit Limit: <b style="color: #00e500 ;"> $@Model.CreditLimit.ToString().ToLocaleString()</b> </p>`

I am changing an Int to a String using `ToString()` Then I am trying to format the number I am getting using `ToLocaleString()`. The number looks like this: 80567. I am trying to format it to look like this: 80,567.

The error I get is "string does not contain a definition for "ToLocaleString"

Thoughts?

EDIT: Going to have this issue closed. Found where my error resided. Please refer to this link if you have any questions on the topic: [Link to StackOverFlow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: toLocaleString is available in other languages, not C#, unless you implement an extension method.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't think ToLocaleString would be a method on a string but rather an int because what would it even do for a string like "hello world!" ?

Comment: @dominic-gozza can you please mark an answer as accepted or tell us what's missing?

Answer (score 3):

I see that you want to show money amount, you should use currency NumberFormatInfo for this. First get current CultureInfo or create it for specific language-country:

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
// or
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Then use it to format your number:

```
var creditLimit = 100;
var creditLimitFormatted = creditLimit.ToString("c", culture);
```

The "c" stands for "currency", you can see other possible options in the documentation of [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.90).aspx).

[Formatting Numeric Data for a Specific Culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`@Model.CreditLimit` - this is Integer

`@Model.CreditLimit.ToString()` - this is a String

now you are trying to execute the `ToLocaleString()` which clearly from the error

> "string does not contain a definition for "ToLocaleString"

To do what you want to archive try the solutions below:

`String.Format("{0:n}", @Model.CreditLimit);` //Output: 80,567.00

`string.Format("{0:n0}", @Model.CreditLimit);` // Output: 80567

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `int` (`Int32`) class is not formattable, that is, it's representation does not depend on the culture, for example. You have to roll out your formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) gives a nice overview of the different format types available. It sounds like you want the [Numeric Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString). You'd use it like this

```
int intValue = 123456789;
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 123,456,789.0
```