# Alternative way to format number with Comma

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to write this function that will add a comma to a number?

```
private static string FormatNumber(decimal? number)
{
    if (!number.HasValue)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    // use the different formatter for long numbers
    return number > 99999 ? $"{number.Value:#,###.##}" : $"{number.Value:G29}";
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want a better way?

Comment: What's wrong with this way?

Comment: Do I really need return number > 99999?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
private static string FormatNumber(decimal? number)
{
    if (!number.HasValue)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return $"{number.Value:#,###.##}";
 }
```