# C# UWP how to type a number string and get commas real time in order?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to type numbers into a textbox and have it add a comma after every third number in real time. I need to convert the string of numbers into a real number because I need to do a simple math equation in real time as well. A problem I'm running into is that if I type in order of 1234567 after I hit 4 it adds the comma and then the input box jumps to the beginning of the string. So I type from 1 to 7 I get **5,671,234**

```
private void PriceBox_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PriceBox.Text))
            {
                int x = Int32.Parse(PriceBox.Text, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                float y = x * .50f;
                Half.Text = y.ToString("N0");
                PriceBox.Text = x.ToString("N0");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format a number to have commas after every 3 digit as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number). One way is to hook the `TextChanged` event, convert the current number to a comma separated number, and replace the current text with the comma separated number.

Also, to stop ovetflow exception, you have to unsubscribe from the `TextChanged` event and then subscribe again.

The total event handler is here:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

    /// unsubscribe, so that the replacing doesn't invoke this handler again
    textBox.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
    if(double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out double value))
    {
        textBox.Text = value.ToString("N0");
    }

    /// put the cursor in the end of the text
    textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);

    /// subscribe again
    textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit:**
To allow numeric values only, hook the `PreviewKeyDown` event, allow numeric keys only. like this:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool proceed =
        (e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0 && e.Key <= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number9) ||
        (e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.NumberPad0 && e.Key <= Windows.System.VirtualKey.NumberPad9);
    e.Handled = !proceed;
}
```

And at last, to allow more than 3 commas, I have edited the code, it should allow more than 3 commas now (basically, I replaced `int` with `double`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm at work right now, but I'll give it a try as soon as I get home. If it works I'll be sure to upvote you and mark as correct answer

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code worked. It does up to 3 commas and then it stops. It also allows letters and special characters, but I'll try to figure that out. Thanks again

Comment: I have edited the answer to meet the additional requirements too. Check it.