# c# convert string with comma to number

Tags: c#, string, double

So i have this input: `3,000,000`

And this function return `30000M`:

```
public static decimal? CustomParse(string incomingValue)
{
    decimal val;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(incomingValue.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", ""), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out val))
        return null;
    return val / 100;
}
```

What the best way to convert this kind on input to `numbber` ?

**EDIT**

I also try this::

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
```

And the output is `3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: I need from string not toString

Comment: Your code already does that, can you clarify your question to show what you are trying to get?

Comment: You shouldn't replace the "." and as you're dividing by 100 your result seems correct

Comment: Check what your ```Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture``` is set to. Many Cultures use ',' as the decimal point seperator. So depending on your Culture. 3 might very well be the expected outcome.

Comment: I am trying to get 3000000 from 3,000,000

Comment: @ErofhTor, so what about decimal point and what will be the output in case `1,234,567.89` notice here dot(`.`) in between 7 and 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this

```cs
return Decimal.Parse(incomingValue, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

In en-US '.' is the comma seperator. So it will parse the text correctly.

If culture is set to say "de-DE" 3 would be the expected outcome of the conversion as ',' is the comma seperator.

Your regex however will always give you 3, because it just matches `[0-9]+` regular expressions don' t care about your culture settings. If you want a regex to match your number you'd have to use something like

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(,\d+)*");
```

This would match "123" as well as "123,123" but not "123," or "123." (in witch case it will just match the 123 part).

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFormatProvider` in `decimal.Parse`

```
var format = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberGroupSeparator = ","
};

decimal res = decimal.Parse("3,000,000", format);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
            decimal amount = 0;
            if (!decimal.TryParse("3,000,000.12", NumberStyles.Any, culture, out amount))
            {
```

....
}

Comment: Can you add more explanation?

Answer (score -1):

You are dividing by 100, so your number won't be 3 millions... Here the solution:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      decimal? value = CustomParse("3,000,000");
      Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public static decimal? CustomParse(string incomingValue)
    {
      decimal val;
      if (!decimal.TryParse(incomingValue.Replace(",", ""), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out val))
        return null;
      return val;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will also parse double ? for example 154,500.20