# String Format for up to 2 decimal places or simple integer and with thousand separator - C#

Tags: c#, string

Here is a string format which formats a number up to 2 decimal places and if there are no decimal places then it will show the simple integer itself:

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
```

so `{0:0.##}` will do the job. But I need to have a thousand separator on integer part. so something like `1234.456` should be like `1,234.45`. I know `{0:n0}` will do a thousand separators but how to combine it with the decimal place formatter?

Comment: no, it is not working

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42419283/589259) work? It should keep to the locale, which the current answer doesn't.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Are you talking about my answer, and if so, what does it mean to keep to the locale?

Comment: Well, if I looked at the other answers there, the comma and dot are now strictly used for thousands and decimals. That's not correct e.g. here in NL, where the dot is the thousands separator and the comma denotes the decimals.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes In a format string, the comma is a placeholder for the locale's thousands separator, and the dot is a placeholder for the locale's decimal dot. You will have different output with the same format string on different locales.

Comment: OK, then I guess quite a few of the comments on the other Q/A are off :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:#,##0.##}", 123.0);
```

Comment: What does this do for numbers over 9,999? Why is there a zero after the `#`? Currently this is a code only answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The zero is there because it was originally there and I just prepended the `#,##`. For numbers over 9999 it's going to repeat the thousand separator pattern and insert one after each 3 digits.

Comment: @GSerg Great Man, thank you. Could you please introduce some resources to study about string formatting?

Comment: @InsideMan The only one I've even needed is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting, from which you follow to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings for numbers specifically.