# How to set the decimal places to auto according user entries in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have textbox receives number by the user.
the problem is that I want to format this textbox to show the numbers as the next face:
15000.25 >> 15,000.25
I used FormatNumber Function:

```
dim x as double
x = FormatNumber(textbox1.text,2)
textbox1.text = x
```

but here the problem is I want to keep the decimal places as entered by the user, examples:

> 15000.225 >> 15,000.225 NOT 15,000.22
> 0.00083   >> 0.00083    NOT 0

I hope my problem is clear.

Comment: Dumb but simple: `dim result = [Double].ToString("N30", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TrimEnd("0"c)`

Comment: See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31330178/2330053)?

Comment: @Jimi please some explain!

Comment: @Idle_Mind I tried must of the formats but nothing happened, I don't want to be bound by an exact number of decimal places

Comment: Are we dealing with ONE number in the TextBox, or multiple numbers?

Comment: @Idle_Mind multiple numbers

Comment: one number in each time but every time is different @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the next solution:

```
Dim xStr As String = CStr(Me.Text)
Dim xCount As Integer = Len(Split(xStr, ".")(1))
Me.textbox1.Text = FormatNumber(Me.Text, xCount)
```

it's working for me.
thanks

Comment: This will fail if there is no "." in the input.  You should check for that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dbl As Double
    If Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text, dbl) Then
        Dim parts() As String = dbl.ToString.Split(".")
        Dim strDecimalPattern As String = ""
        If parts.Length = 2 Then
            strDecimalPattern = New String("#", parts(1).Length)
        End If
        Dim strPattern As String = "{0:#,##0" &
            If(strDecimalPattern <> "", ".", "") &
            strDecimalPattern & "}"
        TextBox1.Text = String.Format(strPattern, dbl)
    End If
End Sub
```