# Convert comma delimited numbers to non-comma delimited decimals

Tags: c#

How to convert form the following format 12,5242.25 to decimal 125242.25 reading a set of data from an excel workseet and am using some internally developed library to which i don't have access to, in order to map the worksheet to a POCO.

```
[ExcelObject("NameFromExcelOfDataCollection")
public class @MyClass
{
    ....
    
    [ExcelColumn(Name = "excel_column_name", format: "????")]
    public decimal MyNumber { get; set; }
   
    ....
}
```

I found this [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number?newreg=54dc550d0c4c4873b8140247fbb4d470) which shows how to do it the other way arround.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse("12,5242.25"));` ?

Comment: See [`decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0) methods.

Comment: @TheGeneral, the value is comming from an excel worksheet and I want to specify this during deserialization as format in some custom attribute

Comment: For what it's worth, this isn't what "comma-delimited" means.  If I have a string that looks like `"Beans, 4.95, per lb, 04:00:00"` that's a comma delimited string - there are four fields in a record, with the fields delimited by commas (effectively 4 columns in a row (speaking database-ese)).  What you are talking about is a "thousands separator" (not all cultures use a comma (for example, en-CA uses a comma, but fr-CA uses a space)).

Comment: good comment, helps a lot